# Was Defense of Children International Palestine declared a terrorist organization?

Tags: israel, terrorism

According to this [CNN interview](https://www.cnn.com/videos/tv/2023/12/04/amanpour-state-epartment-official-resignation-josh-paul.cnn) with [Josh Paul, a now resigned, former director at US Department of State,](https://www.npr.org/2023/10/19/1207037984/josh-paul-resign-state-department-military-assistance-israel-gaza)

> I was part of the human rights vetting process for arms going to Israel. A charity called Defense of Children International Palestine drew our attention at the state department to the sexual assault, a rape, of a 13 year old boy in an Israeli prison at [Moskobiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscovia_Detention_Centre) in Jerusalem. We examined these allegations, we  believed they were they were credible. We put them to the government of Israel. You know what happened the next day? **The IDF went into the DCIP offices and removed all their computers and declared them a terrorist entity.**

Did the IDF or Israel declare the Defense of Children International Palestine a terrorist entity, and if so what was the stated reason (if provided)? Is there any evidence this happened *after* they raised allegations about child-rape in detention centers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "Next day": false, but general sequence of events may be true

**Aside from the testimony in the video, there is no evidence I found that the USA notified Israel of the DCIP report** but the term "the next day" can NOT possibly be literal.

However, it's possible that between 2-10 and 7-28 the Americans notified Israel, which raided the offices on 7-29 and subsequently decreed less than three months later that Defense of Children International (which has offices in the USA too) is a terrorist organization.

- [2021-02-10: Defense of Children International Palestine report on child sexual abuse in an Israeli detention center](https://www.dci-palestine.org/israeli_interrogator_sexually_assaults_palestinian_child_detainee)
- [2021-07-29: DCIP report on IDF Raids offices](https://www.dci-palestine.org/israeli_forces_raid_dcip_office_confiscate_computers_and_client_files), [YouTube video with timestamp](https://youtu.be/-fijWG2J1s8?si=1ObGqUBesVjs_sYu) and [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DCIPalestine/status/1420663222764462080)
- [2021-08-13: UN Publishes claim of raid and acknowledges stolen documents and equipment](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2021/08/un-experts-condemn-raid-west-bank-ngo-urge-israel-meaningfully-probe-child)

  > GENEVA (13 August 2021) – UN human rights experts* have called on the Government of Israel to immediately return confidential documents and office equipment that its military seized from the offices of Defense for Children International-Palestine (DCIP) in Al-Bireh, in the occupied West Bank.
- [2021-10-22: Human Rights Watch condemns the 10-19 terrorist-declaration by the IDF](https://www.hrw.org/news/2021/10/22/israel/palestine-designation-palestinian-rights-groups-terrorists), also later condemned by the [CIA](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/22/cia-report-israel-palestinian-rights-groups)

## The material basis for the "terrorist" declaration: Boycott Divestment Sanctions

Israel acknowledges DCIP as "focused on the treatment of Palestinian children". Their problem seems to be *"The NGO promotes
boycotts of Israel in coordination with NGOs in Europe and the USA."* [From the State of Israel's report *"Terrorism in Suits: The Ties Between NGOs promoting BDS and Terrorist Organizations"*](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/generalpage/terrorists_in_suits/en/De-Legitimization%20Brochure.pdf) the DCIP is a "terrorist organization" because of these three enumerated "activities" pertaining to BDS,

> - The NGO is a signatory to the 2005 Palestinian Civil Society Call for BDS.
> - The NGO has a network of ties with boycott-promoting NGOs in the
>   Palestinian Authority as well as internationally, primarily in the US.
> - DCI-P is a member-organization of the umbrella group for
>   Palestinian delegitimization and boycott-promoting NGOs known
>   as the Palestinian Human Rights Organizations Council (PHROC).

Comment: Your last sentence is missing some words.

Comment: @jwodder thought you wanted a lil' extra.

Answer (score 5):

The first part of the Q seems easy enough to answer. [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2022-08-18/ty-article/.premium/israel-raids-outlawed-palestinian-rights-groups-offices-in-west-bank/00000182-af5a-d1f9-a59e-ff7a07050000):

> In October 2021, Defense Minister Benny Gantz signed an order declaring six Palestinian organizations as terrorist organizations: Addameer, Al-Haq, the Bisan Center for Research & Development, Defense for Children International-Palestine, the Union of Palestinian Women's Committees and the Union of Agricultural Work Committees. The organizations deny this allegation.
>
> Thursday's early morning raids represent a serious escalation just a month after the country's Defense Ministry demanded that lawyers representing the six Palestinian NGOs designated as terror groups receive official permission from the finance and defense ministers to represent the organizations, or face a prison sentence of up to seven years.
>
> The new requirement came just two days ahead of a hearing on the legality of the decision to outlaw the organizations. [One of these lawyers] said it was "extremely difficult to avoid interpreting it [the demand] as a government threat made against a lawyer engaging in entirely legal work."

However since 6 NGOs were apparently all banned at the same time, it's a bit less clear what the trigger might have been. An older [piece](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2021-10-22/ty-article/.premium/gantz-declares-six-palestinian-ngos-terrorist-organizations/0000017f-e795-dea7-adff-f7ff13bf0000) quotes the government saying that the 6 organizations funneled money to the  Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine (PFLP).

Comment: FWTW, the Guardian says that a classified, but apparently leaked CIA report disagreed with the Israeli gov't assessment https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/22/cia-report-israel-palestinian-rights-groups